# SharePoint 2013 Library Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a user that can create a document library in our SharePoint 2013 site. The problem is after she creates it she is not given full control over the library so she isn't allowed to grant permissions to other users.

When someone creates a library aren't they by default the owner of that library? If that isn't how it works by default is there something I can do to make that happen?

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

you could create or modify the permission level of the user's group. Thats a way to go

Here is a link: 
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx